# SSL newbie - in which scenario a client needs a certificate?

Tags: tls, java

I am new to SSL/TLS, and need some help with understanding.

I am running a java application, which is able to consume HTTP and HTTPS URLs as a client from the internet via httpClient. For that, I don't need to add any certificate or keys and do not have to generate anything.

Now imagine the client would need a certificate and I am getting a SSLException. What does the server have to change so that I would get a SSLException when I try to connect? Is there a kind of a setting? And is this "two-way-ssl" then or is this called "ssl client certificate authentication"?

Is there a common website, against which I could test this scenario?

Once I copied a certificate from the browser into a file and installed it on my workstation, then I was able to use Firefox to enter a specific website. Was this one a self-signed certificate then, which is somehow private?

Comment: It would help a lot if you post the actual full error, and would help even more if you post a link to the site where you are getting the error. All we're going off of is your interpretation of what you are seeing, and as you say, you are new to all this.

Comment: A quick Google search for the terms you list "two-way-ssl" gives you what you need to know about those terms. Once you do that, then "how to enable mutual TLS" gets you what you need to do to configure a server for it.

Comment: As for your last section, you don't provide any info to be able to answer that.